# Wordpress if logged out, Laravel if logged in

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, laravel-routing

Well, the title explains it well... I do use Laravel for a control panel and Wordpress as the frontend facing the "outside world".

I need to use the same URL for both, I've accomplished it partially processing Wordpress as a Laravel view, but I have troubles with the Laravel namespaces/autoload and the Wordpress functionality.

It's easy to do what I need with .htaccess considering default routes... But the main trouble is with the index. The idea is to have the / route with Wordpress by default and with Laravel when logged in. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, sadly nobody answered. But I did it. Simply I did use a cookie to know where am I.

On laravel's www/index.php

```
if($_COOKIE['laravel']||$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']=='/login'){
    require __DIR__ . '/../private/bootstrap/autoload.php';
    $app = require_once __DIR__ . '/../private/bootstrap/start.php';
    $app->run();
}else{
    define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);
    require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wordpress/wp-blog-header.php' );
}
```

On controllers/UserController.php function login()

```
if(Input::has('remember'))
   setcookie ('laravel','yes!');
else
   setcookie ('laravel','right!',time()+60*60*24*30);
```

On controllers/UserController.php function logout()

```
setcookie('laravel', null, -1);
```

Hope it helps somebody :)